# The container created by docker-compose does not see the entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I encountered a problem in docker-compose that the `api` service doesn't see the `entrypoint.sh` and crashes. Specific error:

> exec /app/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:3.1.0-slim

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
WORKDIR app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install build-essential libpq-dev autoconf autogen libtool
EXPOSE 3000

COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install

COPY ./entrypoint.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`.docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  es:
    image: elasticsearch:8.7.0
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms750m -Xmx750m
      - xpack.security.enabled=false

  db:
    image: postgres:14.0-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD= ...
    ports:
      - 5431:5432

  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.11-alpine

  api:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://es:9200
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
```

The file structure of the container created for the `api` service:
[image: structure]

Also, strangely enough, the dockerfile has not changed since it was successfully started. I can't figure out where the problem is. Help me, please :(

I tried deleting all images, all containers and all volumes, none of this helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable in shebang of `entrypoint.sh` is not found inside docker container. Install the executable or change shabang. Most probably you have bash and bash is not inside the container, for exmaple.